# Saving nodes in iterative Adaptive Simpson quadrature method (Matlab)

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, simpsons-rule, quadrature

Implementing on Matlab the Simpson adaptive rule to approximate an integral (the following code), I am struggling with saving nodes correctly. I have tried different solutions, but none of them seems to be the right one. Any suggestions?

```
[S, nodes] = SimpsonAdapt (f, a, b, tol, hmin)

h = b - a;
c = (a + b) / 2;
d = (a + c) / 2;
e = (c + b) / 2;
fa = feval (f, a);
fb = feval (f, b);
fc = feval (f, c);
fd = feval (f, d);
fe = feval (f, e);
nodes = [a b];


S1 = (h/6)*(fa + 4*fc + fb);
S2 = (h/(12))*(fa + 4*fd + 2*fc + 4*fe + fb);

E2 = (1/(15))*(S2 - S1);

if abs(E2) <= tol && (b - a) < hmin
    S = S2 + E2;
    nodes =[];
else
    [Q1, nodi1] = SimpsonAdapt (f, a, c, tol/2, hmin, nodes);
    [Q2, nodi2] = SimpsonAdapt (f, c, b, tol/2, hmin, nodes);
    nodes = [nodes, nodi1];
    nodes = [nodes, nodi2];
    
    S = Q1 + Q2;
end
nodes = unique(nodes);
end
```

Comment: What do you mean with "saving nodes"? To avoid the multiple evaluation at the same point?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I should generate a figure where nodes are marked, but my implementation actually is saving about 1200 points whereas they would be, at most, 300. So I don't think I am saving only the nodes. By the way the multiple evaluation must be avoided by using "nodes = unique(nodes);".

Comment: No, I mean the multiple evaluation in the recursion. In the `else` branch, the already known values at `a,d,c,e,b` are again evaluated in the next level, two times in the case of `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodes list that is returned is the list of points used to evaluate the quadrature formula. You should decide which nodes these are and use that decision uniformly. You first give only the interval end-points. However, in the branching you return the 6th order Richardson extrapolation of the Simpson values, which uses all 5 points `[a,d,c,e,b]`.

In the composition, you simply have to remove the repeated middle point `c` once,

```
nodes = [ node1(1:end-1) node2 ]
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892251/building-a-recursive-function-in-matlab-to-draw-adaptive-trapezoidal-quadrature for a similar question.

Using the adapted python code (which does not care about saving function evaluations)

```
def adapt_simpson_quad(f,a,b,tol):
    def recurse_simp(a,b,tol):
        x = np.linspace(a,b,5)
        y = f(x)
        s1 = (b-a)*(y[0]+4*y[2]+y[4])/6
        s2 = (b-a)*(y[0]+4*y[1]+2*y[2]+4*y[3]+y[4])/12
        if abs(s2 - s1) < tol: return list(x[::2]), s1
        if abs(s2 - s1) < 15*tol: return list(x), s2
        node1, approx1 = recurse_simp(a,x[2],tol/2);
        node2, approx2 = recurse_simp(x[2],b,tol/2);
        return node1[:-1] + node2, approx1+approx2;
    return recurse_simp(a,b,tol);
```

gives reduced node lists without any clean-up and results in plots like

[image]

for the integration task

```
f = lambda x: (cos(x**0.25))/(1+x**1.5)
a=1; b=1.71;
```

or more demonstrative

[image]

for the task

```
f = lambda x: sin(pi*x**2);
a=0; b=1;
```