# Why is my adaptive quadrature worse than the composite Simpson rule?

Tags: numerical-methods, python, quadrature

I wrote a basic adaptive quadrature that uses the difference between trapezoidal and Simpson rule to estimate the error on each intervall and makes the mesh finer if needed:

```
def adaptQuad(f, Meshes, tol): 
 M = Meshes[-1]
 h = np.diff(M) #Calculate intervall lengths h_i
 mp = (M[1:]+M[:-1])/2 #calculate midpoints
 fx = f(M); fm = f(mp) #evaluate f(x)
 trp = h*(fx[:-1]+2*fm+fx[1:])/4 #evaluate trapezoidal (on each interval)
 simp = h*(fx[:-1]+4*fm+fx[1:])/6 #evaluate Simpson (on each interval)
 err = abs(trp-simp) #Difference between the rules
 if sum(err) > tol: #are we done? 
    ref = np.nonzero(err > sum(err)/len(err))[0] #Refine mesh where needed
    Meshes.append(np.sort(np.append(M,mp[ref])))
    return adaptQuad(f, Meshes, tol) #recursion
 return sum(simp), Meshes #return composite simpson
```

I wanted to compare it to the composite simpson rule:

```
def compSimpson(f,a,b,N):
 x,h = np.linspace(a,b,N+1,retstep=True)
 midP = (x[1:]+x[:-1])/2
 x = x[1:-1]
 return h/6 *(f(a) + 2*sum(f(x))+4*sum(f(midP))+f(b))
```

But when I tried it on:

```
f = lambda x: 1/(1+25*x**2)
```

with the following:

```
Q,M = adaptQuad(f,[np.linspace(-1,1,5)],0.001)
Q_simp = compSimpson(f,-1,1,len(M[-1])-1) #Try Comp. Simpson with as many intervals
I = integrate.quad(f,-1,1)[0]
print("Error composite Simpson: ", abs(Q_simp-I))         
print("Error adaptive quad: ", abs(Q-I))
```

I get:
Error composite Simpson:  5.274740111360643e-08
Error adaptive quad:  1.2452016172281866e-05

I tried some different total tolerances and most of the time the composite simpson rule outperforms the adaptive quadrature? This shouldn't be possible but I can't find my error in the implementation either, I'd be glad for some help:)

**Edit:** Here an illustration of how the Mesh evolves over time (the nodes are the dots, each line of same coloured dots shows one Meshes[i])
[image: Mesh illustration]

Comment: How far from uniform do your nodes actually end up being? This rule of only demanding that the apparent error is bigger than the average in order to choose to refine in those locations seems a bit pessimistic to me.

Comment: You're right, but I think it should still work, shouldn't it? I added a picture that shows the "node-evolution" over time, to me is seems as if the final mesh should definitely be better then equidistant one.

Comment: Have you tried with a nonperiodic function? There is some extra theory where some methods perform unexpectedly well on periodic inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, your refinement strategy is skewed. It prefers small intervals over large, or in other words, it is too eager to split large intervals.

What you really should want is that each interval contributes to the error according to their length, that is, a constant error density. For that purpose I would change your code to

```
def adaptQuad(f, Meshes, tol): 
  M = Meshes[-1]
  h = np.diff(M) #Calculate interval lengths h_i
  mp = (M[1:]+M[:-1])/2 #calculate midpoints
  fx = f(M); fm = f(mp) #evaluate f(x)
  trp = h*(fx[:-1]+2*fm+fx[1:])/4 #evaluate trapezoidal (on each interval)
  simp = h*(fx[:-1]+4*fm+fx[1:])/6 #evaluate Simpson (on each interval)
  err = abs(trp-simp) #Difference between the rules

  ref = err > tol*h
  if not ref.any():  #are we done? 
    return sum(simp), Meshes #return composite Simpson

  Meshes.append(np.sort(np.append(M,mp[ref])))
  return adaptQuad(f, Meshes, tol) #recursion
```

This equalizes the results somewhat,

```
Error composite Simpson:  1.4457746544405126e-07
Error adaptive quad:  7.845544380824521e-07
```

Both are far below the desired error bound `1e-3`. But already for `tol=1e-4` there is again the marked difference towards the composite method,

```
Error composite Simpson:  1.935168691957756e-10
Error adaptive quad:  3.361578637672835e-08
```

The second point to consider is a little more subtle, the adaptive strategy produces a subdivision for the error of the trapezoidal method, but returns the result for the Simpson method. While the result is better, the error bound `tol*interval_length` is not valid or very pessimistic.

Another effect is that a greater density of small segments is required for the trapezoidal method in "stiff" regions than for the Simpson method. This means that the adaptive strategy has unnecessary computations in these stiff regions, while the equidistant composite Simpson still has sufficient segment density there, and greater density in more flat regions, thus giving an overall better result.

Or in other words, if you want a fair comparison, take the composite trapezoidal method with the same number of function evaluations.

See [Saving nodes in iterative Adaptive Simpson quadrature method (Matlab)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3728179/saving-nodes-in-iterative-adaptive-simpson-quadrature-method-matlab) for another approach where the recursion actually splits the interval and the requested error bound.

Comment: +1. A few actual comments: 1. Your description of the effect I noticed explains it a lot better; I just had the more rough intuition that this rule would probably trigger refinement in something like half of subintervals which seemed wasteful.

Comment: 2. To the OP, I suggest looking into the theory of Richardson extrapolation if you haven't already. From this point of view, this setup of comparing the trapezoidal and Simpson rules should be used to detect when the result of the adaptive trapezoidal rule is good. For a smooth enough integrand, you can do further Richardson extrapolation to detect when the result of adaptive Simpson is good.

Comment: 3. It is not super important, but I would suggest normalizing the stopping criterion, since as it is, if you have uniform error density, you would stop when the apparent error estimate falls below tol * (b-a) rather than tol.